# How to make uwsgi --emperor run as daemon

Tags: daemon, uwsgi

I'm using yaml. It has a line says : `daemonize : /var/www/apps/myapp.log`

If `uwsgi -y vassals/myappconfig.yaml`, the website runs in background. I can do other things in terminal, even logout. This is the effect I'm expecting.

If `uwsgi --emperor vassals`, the website can run, but it stuck up in terminal. I must use `ctrl + c` to end it to return to terminal. Then the website is down. That's not what I'm expecting.

I don't want to use things like `nohup`. If `uwsgi --emperor` is not the right solution, I'd rather to load websites one by one, all run daemonized.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can pass `--daemonize <logfile>` to the emperor too