# Uwsgi running in foreground though it shouldn't

Tags: uwsgi

This is my UWSGI config:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = $APPUSER
gid = $APPGROUP
socket = $SOCK
processes = 4
chdir = $APPDIR
virtualenv = $APPVENV
pythonpath = $APPVENV/bin/python
module = run
callable = app
emperor-pidfile = $APPDIR/emperor.pid
daemonize = /var/log/emperor.log
```

When emperor runs it does create the emperor log file but it is running in the foreground and not in the background as a daemon.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also pass `--daemonize <logfile>` to the emperor.

And see [How to make uwsgi --emperor run as daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796241/)

Comment: I'm a bit confused though, I'm running it with this command: ```uwsgi --emperor app.ini``` and in the app.ini (which is above) is the daemon line. Is that not achieving the same thing?